# How do I add an .x and .y suffix to all duplicate variables after the join?

Tags: r, join, dplyr, plyr

I was using dplyr::left_join() initially, but it didn't have the match = "first" argument that I wanted that was available in plyr::join. The problem now is that my remaining code has .x and .y for duplicate variables so I can't just use janitor::clean_names().

To give you a sense of what I'm talking about:

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
name1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
name2 <- c("k", "l", "m", "n", "o")
name3 <- c("u", "v", "w", "x", "y")
name4 <- c("z", "a", "b", "c", "d")

df <- data.frame(id, name1, name2, name3, name4)

id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
name1 <- c("f", "i", "j", "k", "l")
name2 <- c("p", "q", "r", "s", "t")
name3 <- c("z", "a", "b", "c", "d")
name5 <- c("z", "a", "b", "c", "d")
df2 <- data.frame(id, name1, name2, name3, name5)

library(plyr)

df_join <- plyr::join(df, df2, by=c("id"), type="left", match="first")
```

I want to turn the duplicate variables (name1, name2, name3) into the following:

Right side: name1.x, name2.x, name3.x
Left side: name1.y, name2.y, name3.y

How would I go about doing this? janitor::clean_names() seems to only add "_2" for the left hand side variables.

Comment: Maybe `df %>% left_join(df2, by = 'id') %>% group_by(id) %>% slice_head()`?

Comment: @jpdugo17 slice_head() is only outputting observation for me. What if I'm joining by more than one column?

Comment: I suspect `group_by(id, id2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `dplyr::left_join`. To mimic the behavior of `plyr::join`, just turn duplicated `id`s in your right dataframe into `NA`s or any other values that will not be found in the `id` column of your left dataframe. For instance,

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% 
  mutate(id = replace(id, duplicated(id), NA_integer_)) %>% 
  left_join(df, ., by = "id", suffix = c(".y", ".x"))
```

Output

```
  id name1.y name2.y name3.y name4 name1.x name2.x name3.x name5
1  1       a       k       u     z       f       p       z     z
2  2       b       l       v     a       i       q       a     a
3  3       c       m       w     b       j       r       b     b
4  4       d       n       x     c       k       s       c     c
5  5       e       o       y     d       l       t       d     d
```

The two dataframes are

```
> df
  id name1 name2 name3 name4
1  1     a     k     u     z
2  2     b     l     v     a
3  3     c     m     w     b
4  4     d     n     x     c
5  5     e     o     y     d
> df2
  id name1 name2 name3 name5
1  1     f     p     z     z
2  2     i     q     a     a
3  3     j     r     b     b
4  4     k     s     c     c
5  5     l     t     d     d
6  1   XXX   XXX   XXX   XXX
```

---

This one should work for any number of columns you want to join by (as long as you specify them).

```
libaray(dplyr)

by <- c("id1", "id2")
df2 %>%                                    # v-v------------------- Not a typo. You need two commas here.
  mutate(across(!!by) %>% `[<-`(duplicated(.), , value = NA)) %>% 
  left_join(df, ., by = by, suffix = c(".y", ".x"))
```

The two dataframes

```
> df
  id1 id2 name1 name2 name3 name4
1   1   5     a     k     u     z
2   2   4     b     l     v     a
3   3   3     c     m     w     b
4   4   2     d     n     x     c
5   5   1     e     o     y     d
> df2
  id1 id2 name1 name2 name3 name5
1   1   5     f     p     z     z
2   2   4     i     q     a     a
3   3   3     j     r     b     b
4   4   2     k     s     c     c
5   5   1     l     t     d     d
6   3   3   XXX   XXX   XXX   XXX
```

Output

```
  id1 id2 name1.y name2.y name3.y name4 name1.x name2.x name3.x name5
1   1   5       a       k       u     z       f       p       z     z
2   2   4       b       l       v     a       i       q       a     a
3   3   3       c       m       w     b       j       r       b     b
4   4   2       d       n       x     c       k       s       c     c
5   5   1       e       o       y     d       l       t       d     d
```

Comment: What if I am joining by two columns?

Comment: Hi @hy9fesh, see the update.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
name1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
name2 <- c("k", "l", "m", "n", "o")
name3 <- c("u", "v", "w", "x", "y")
name4 <- c("z", "a", "b", "c", "d")

df <- data.frame(id, name1, name2, name3, name4)

id <- c(1, 1, 3, 3, 5)
name1 <- c("f", "i", "j", "k", "l")
name2 <- c("p", "q", "r", "s", "t")
name3 <- c("z", "a", "b", "c", "d")
name5 <- c("z", "a", "b", "c", "d")
df2 <- data.frame(id, name1, name2, name3, name5)

#not desired result
df %>% left_join(df2, by = 'id')
#>   id name1.x name2.x name3.x name4 name1.y name2.y name3.y name5
#> 1  1       a       k       u     z       f       p       z     z
#> 2  1       a       k       u     z       i       q       a     a
#> 3  2       b       l       v     a    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>
#> 4  3       c       m       w     b       j       r       b     b
#> 5  3       c       m       w     b       k       s       c     c
#> 6  4       d       n       x     c    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>
#> 7  5       e       o       y     d       l       t       d     d

df_join <- plyr::join(df, df2, by=c("id"), type="left", match="first")
df_join 
#>   id name1 name2 name3 name4 name1 name2 name3 name5
#> 1  1     a     k     u     z     f     p     z     z
#> 2  2     b     l     v     a  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
#> 3  3     c     m     w     b     j     r     b     b
#> 4  4     d     n     x     c  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
#> 5  5     e     o     y     d     l     t     d     d


df %>% left_join(df2, by = 'id') %>% group_by(id) %>% slice_head() %>% as.data.frame()
#>   id name1.x name2.x name3.x name4 name1.y name2.y name3.y name5
#> 1  1       a       k       u     z       f       p       z     z
#> 2  2       b       l       v     a    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>
#> 3  3       c       m       w     b       j       r       b     b
#> 4  4       d       n       x     c    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>
#> 5  5       e       o       y     d       l       t       d     d
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing the data from @jpdugo17 (so we actually have duplicate ids), we can use {powerjoin}

```r
library(powerjoin)
library(dplyr)

power_left_join(
  df, 
  df2 %>% summarize_by_keys(slice(across(), 1)), # take 1st row by keys
  by = "id"
)
#>   id name1.x name2.x name3.x name4 name1.y name2.y name3.y name5
#> 1  1       a       k       u     z       f       p       z     z
#> 2  2       b       l       v     a    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>
#> 3  3       c       m       w     b       j       r       b     b
#> 4  4       d       n       x     c    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>
#> 5  5       e       o       y     d       l       t       d     d
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>